# Loader won't clear from memory

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been struggling on this for some time.
I have a loader that loads an external image every ten seconds. My problem is that although i have tried all kind of things to clear it after i am done with it, it keeps consuming more      memory every time it loads the image.

As you can see, in the end of the code i am trying everything that i could find without any results. The memory usage keeps getting bigger every time the  **myLoader.load(fileRequest)** occurs.

Any thoughts?

:-(

```
var tenSec:Timer = new Timer(1000,10);
var image:DisplayObject;
var myLoader:Loader;

tenSec.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
tenSec.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
tenSec.start();

function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void
{
  myLoader= new Loader();
  myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderReady);
  myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderReady, false, 0, true );

  var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://"+ip+"/radiosite/image.jpg?nocache=" + new Date().getTime());
  myLoader.load(fileRequest);
  function onLoaderReady(e:Event)
  {
     image = myLoader.content;
     addChild(image);
     image = null;
     myLoader.unload();
     myLoader = null;
     System.gc();
     fileRequest = null;
  }
  tenSec.reset();
  tenSec.start();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance: You are calling `addChild(image);` every time you load a new image, but never remove the `image` child from the `stage`. Call `addChild` once outside of `onTimerComplete`, and just replace the contents.

There is no need to nullify the loader `myLoader`, `fileRequest` and especially `image`. You're trying too hard.

Also, don't force garbage collection. The Flash runtime will do this for you when it needs to be done. Using `System.gc` as a work-around won't nullify the remaining links in the memory tree.

Lastly, using a Timer (every 1 second) to reload the image is probably not a good idea. In some cases it will take longer than 1s to load the image. Instead use asynchronous function recursion to fetch a new image: only when the image is done loading should you wait 1 second (use an interval instead at this point) to fetch the new image.

Comment: I think you are perfectly right, for some reason i didn't think to comment out the addChild to see if this causes the problem!

One more question is:
How can i add the **image** since its null before the **onTimerComplete** and i can't instantiate a DisplayObject(var image:DisplayObject=new DisplayObject();)?

Comment: AWWGG..Ignore me, i'm tired.... I just added the same code to load the image once outside of onTimerComplete.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @StratosIon please vote up if it was helpful, accept the answer if it was the solution. ty, and glad i could help!

Comment: IT was more than helpful zamnuts but i tried to vote you and it says "Vote up requires 15 reputation" :-(

Comment: @StratosIon ah yes! contribute to SO and make that reputation! ;) cheers!